# how to force PopupWindow.dismiss() to call synchronously, instead of dispatch for later?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a PopupWindow that looks just like any example PopupWindow you could find on StackOverflow.

It has a .dismiss() handler that looks like any dismiss handler:

```
    reportPopup.setOnDismissListener( () -> {
        reportPopup = null;
        reportPopupHTML = null;
        reportWebView = null;
    } );
```

and I have a test on the handler, which looks like this:

```
ma.reportPopup.dismiss();

//  assertNull(ma.reportPopupHTML);
//  assertNull(ma.reportPopup);
//  assertNull(ma.reportWebView);
```

Note the comment markers; the assertions fail because they think the popup is still up.

Some of my other PopupWindows dismiss synchronously, so my similar assertions pass, but this one fails. Feel free to ask for more code, but it's all vanilla Android. The general question is what can make a .dismiss() dispatch a handler instead of just dismissing and immediately calling its callback?

Guess what? The production code has no problem.

---

the test rig is Espresso with most Espresso features turned off (because my tests try to treat view objects like objects), and most test cases start with @UiThreadTest

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add some delay before you start assertion like Thread.sleep(1000)

Comment: But Thread.sleep() is against my religion! Oookay I'll try it. I forgot to mention I always use @UiThreadTest. The inner question remains; why can't dismiss() finish its complete job (except refreshing the screen) synchronously?

Comment: It didn't work, even up to one second. So now a related question is, from a @UiThreadTest, do I briefly release the view thread and allow it to process its handlers?

Comment: I thought you are doing some unit testing. Are you doing UI tests? Which framework are you using?